# How to get exactly model number of google pixel device?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, android-10.0, google-pixel

I use the Google Pixel XL which has model number is G-2PW2100.
When I use Build.MODEL, it will return for Pixel XL.
So How can I get the exact model number of Google pixel device?

Comment: Try using Build.PRODUCT https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#PRODUCT

Comment: I try all the fields in Build. But don't have exactly the model number.